# Feasible to dig out a cellar extension without disturbing the surface/upper ground?

Tags: excavation

I am wondering how feasible it might be to dig out a cellar that would extend an existing basement. The celler would go lower than the current basement and be about 3 feet below ground level, so there would be stairs in the basement leading down into the new cellar. How feasible would it be to dig this out from the basement without doing an excavation from the ground?

(The reason for doing the excavation this way is that the property is in an HOA that might oppose anything visible above ground, even if the ground would be restored to normal after construction.)

Comment: I might be wrong on this, but I would expect any HOA rules would have terms on structural modifications which, even as a foundation (be it basement walls) or dirt - is still in the terms of a structural modification. Then there is usually improvement clauses etc. And permits for this type of work is needed. Not to mention safety of this approach. Obviously dependent on the soil makeup, it is feasible (think tunnels for subways and mines) but I'd expect the cost to be dramatic vs. the negotiation with an HOA/municipality. Just my thoughts.

Comment: It sounds like a great way to disturb footings, with all the attendant problems. In any case you'll have a disturbance above ground unless you want to be working on it longer than Andy Dufresne. The excavator might be less obnoxious than the bucket brigade.